# References for asparenum environment with counters depending on section

Tags: cross-referencing, itemize, counters

I'm writing math lectures using my own environment for definitions:

```
\newenvironment{mydefs}
{\begin{asparaenum}[\P\slshape\thesection.a]}
{\end{asparaenum}}
```

So every definition is numbered like "section_number.letter" (ex. 3.a)

But then I've got troubles with referencing to defs. No matter what section is it,

```
\begin{mydefs}
\item
\label{123}
Something
\end{mydefs}
....
\ref{123}
```

I'm getting "1.letter" instead of "section_number.letter" (ex. 1.b instead of 3.b). Hope, you can help me to handle this

P.S. I'd really like to keep this numeration (section.letter) style if it's possible.

Thanx

Comment: Can you please complete your code snippets to an commpilable MWE?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. It is really hard for anybody to help you without this information since any solution may not work well with, for example, the class you are using. (So you'll get answers in the end but they are less likely to solve your problem.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest `enumitem` rather than the pretty inflexible `paralist`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newenvironment{mydefs}
  {\begin{enumerate}[
     nosep,
     label=\P\slshape\thesection.\alph*\ ,
     ref=\thesection.\alph*,
     leftmargin=0pt,labelwidth=0pt,align=left,itemindent=\parindent,labelsep=0pt
   ]}
  {\end{enumerate}}
\begin{document}
\section{title}
\begin{mydefs}
\item\label{1}
Something
\item\label{2}
Something
\item\label{3}
Something
\end{mydefs}

\section{Another}

\begin{mydefs}
\item\label{11}
Something
\item\label{22}
Something
\item\label{33}
Something
\end{mydefs}

1: \ref{1}

2: \ref{2}

3: \ref{3}

11: \ref{11}

22: \ref{22}

33: \ref{33}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The slanted number is really awful.

Comment: Why not `\newlist` and `\setlist` since you're using `enumitem`? Also, although this in fact answers the question, it doesn't actually show that it answers the question since the MWE doesn't show that the correct section number will be used for sections numbered greater than 1, right? Adding `4: \ref{4}

\section{another}

\begin{mydefs}
  \item\label{4}
\end{mydefs}` in case it is useful.

Comment: @cfr I don't think `\newlist` performs any better than this: it's intended more for defining new types of nesting lists. I added a more complete example.

Answer (score 0):

The `asparaenum` environment can be emulated by the [`enumitem`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/enumitem/enumitem.pdf) package.

The option `wide` emulates *items as paragraphs* and the compact lists with the options `noitemsep` and `nosep`.

`\newlist` creates customized lists based in `itemize`, `enumerate` and `description`.

### Example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{mydefs}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[mydefs]{label=\P\slshape\thesection.\alph*,wide,noitemsep,nosep}

\begin{document}
\begin{mydefs}
\item\label{123}
Something
\item B
\end{mydefs}

As in \ref{123} we ...
\end{document}
```

### Result

[image]